# Numpy array not showing properly

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm super new to numpy and I'm trying to create arrays.

```
import numpy as np
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [11,22,33,44]
array = np.array([list1,list2])
```

but instead of showing the array like this:

```
array([[1,2,3,4,5],
       [11,22,33,44]])
```

it shows:

```
array([list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), list([11, 22, 33, 44])], dtype=object)
```

I'm using python 3 and I have no idea what to do, pls help
and here is a screenshot:

[image: screen shot]

edit:

I just tried something and this is becoming weirder, I don't even know how to describe this:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: This does desired output for me

Comment: The code you're using in the screenshot is different from that in your question. Please edit your question to match

Comment: I'm using anaconda, I originally downloaded the python 2 environment, then I decided to also download python 3 environment using anaconda navigator. Thus the numpy package was not included, so I had to download it using pip install. Maybe my download messed up, is there a way to uninstall a package then reinstall it using pip?

Comment: I don't even think this is pip's fault, I just tried to create a zero array and it worked just fine.

Comment: The given code works perfect for me and I'm not able to see your screenshot so can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

In [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html) matrix , (in any matrix for that matter) , the number of elements in each rows should be same . In your code , list1 contains 5 elements and list2 contains 4 elements , that's why it gives "arrays of list" . For the output to be matrix , number of elements in each list should be same .

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured out my own problem, list1 is bigger than list2. list1 contain 5 elements while list2 has only 4. I guess it makes sense because you can't create a numpy array with 5 numbers on top row  and only 4 on the bottom. All I needed was a simple fix:

```
import numpy as np
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [11,22,33,44]
array = np.array([list1,list2])
```

and it returned the desired response:

```
array([[1,2,3,4],
      [11,22,33,44]])
```